# Unable to fetch data in CQWP programmatically

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I have added a CQWP from visual studio. In that web part, I want to fetch the document names of the document library named "Sample Docs".

My code for doing so is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)     
{
    try
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://..........");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SiteAssets/webparts.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        ContentByQueryWebPart wp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
        wp.Title = "My web part using OM";
        wp.ListUrl = web.Url + "/Sample Docs";
        wp.ListName = "Sample Docs";
        wp.XslLink = web.Url + "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl";
        wp.QueryOverride = "<OrderBy>"+
                           "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" />"+
                           "</OrderBy>"+
                           "</Query>";
       wp.CommonViewFields = "Title,Text";
       webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Right", 0);
       webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
       web.Update();
       Console.WriteLine("Web part added successfully");
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Web part gets added successfully but data is not displayed, the web part gives following error:

[image: Web part in web part page.]

What should I do to resolve my problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you should not have the Query tags at all! Try:

```
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: I added the the startin `<Query>` tag and found the error i.e.: "There is a problem with the query that this Web Part is issuing. Check the configuration of this Web Part and try again."

Comment: I think the key is to remove the query tags completely , I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, it started displaying data, but not from the library specified, i.e. Sample Docs, it is displaying the pages from all sites.

Comment: Could be something with your ListUrl and ListName being wrong

Comment: OK, I an checking it..

Comment: The url on web site while exploring is : `http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1/Sample%20Docs/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and the url which I found while debugging is : `http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1/Sample Docs`. And I also matched the name of Library and the property `wp.ListName`.

Comment: You should probable have the %20 left in the URL

Comment: I don't find %20 you can have a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/ES0ZD9K.png).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10580/discussion-between-robert-lindgren-and-users1100)

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

First -> give the Guid of the list which you want to display, to get the Guid go to the library/list , select Library Setting in the url copy the "List={-----}" parameter value.

Second -> Assign the `WebUrl` property of the Web Part Object.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     try
     {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SiteAssets/webparts.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        ContentByQueryWebPart wp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
        wp.Title = "My web part using OM";                                
        wp.ListGuid = "eff50fad-f899-4e26-a9a4-1b40aedfc9be"; \\ Paste the Guid of List/Library.
        wp.WebUrl = "~SiteCollection";                
        webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Right", 0);
        webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
        web.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Web part added successfully");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

The data is displayed.. :-)